# Why is 'UnhandledAlertException' still being outputted to the Console Window?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

Why is 'UnhandledAlertException' still being outputted to the Console Window?

I have the methods listed below, which use TestNG 'Before' and 'After' method to close modal popups, 
but why is 'UnhandledAlertException' still being outputted to the console window even when im ignoring unhandled alert exceptions.

TestNG Invoked Methods:

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void closeModalPopup() throws Exception {
    basePage.closeModalPopup();
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void closeModalPopup2() throws Exception {
    basePage.closeModalPopup();
}
```

Main methods created to close popups etc:

```
public void waitUntilModalDisapears() {
    WebDriverWait tempWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 60);
    try {
        tempWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".modal-body")));
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
        // Do nothing
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        // do nothing
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // do nothing
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

/** Modal Closer **/
public void closeModalPopup() throws InterruptedException {
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < 10) {
        try {
            jsExecutor.executeScript("var p=document.querySelector('.modal.fade.in button.close span'); if ( p) p.click();");
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
            //Do nothing
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            //do nothing
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // do nothing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        attempts++;
        waitUntilModalDisapears();
    } 
}
```

Jenkins Console Output:

```
11:48:48 Jun 01, 2017 11:48:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
11:48:48 WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.cssSelector: .modal-body)
11:48:48 org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as this is exactly how it will be printed.}
11:48:48   (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
11:48:48   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
11:48:48 Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds: null
11:48:48 Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
11:48:48 System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
11:48:48 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
11:48:48 Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\3\scoped_dir6676_5813}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
11:48:48 Session ID: 738b699457547ad20f328acd1580afab
11:48:48 *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.modal-body}
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor17.newInstance(Unknown Source)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
11:48:48       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:173)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:580)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:576)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.pageObjects.Base_Page.waitUntilModalDisapears(Base_Page.java:706)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.pageObjects.Base_Page.closeModalPopup(Base_Page.java:734)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.utilities.BrowserFactory.closeModalPopup2(BrowserFactory.java:417)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:48:48       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
11:48:48       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
11:48:48       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
11:48:48       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:48:48 
11:48:48 Jun 01, 2017 11:48:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
11:48:48 WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.cssSelector: .modal-body)
11:48:48 org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as this is exactly how it will be printed.}
11:48:48   (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
11:48:48   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
11:48:48 Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds: null
11:48:48 Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
11:48:48 System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
11:48:48 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
11:48:48 Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\3\scoped_dir6676_5813}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
11:48:48 Session ID: 738b699457547ad20f328acd1580afab
11:48:48 *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.modal-body}
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor17.newInstance(Unknown Source)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
11:48:48       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:173)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:580)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:576)
11:48:48       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.pageObjects.Base_Page.waitUntilModalDisapears(Base_Page.java:706)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.pageObjects.Base_Page.closeModalPopup(Base_Page.java:734)
11:48:48       at BuyAGiftFramework.utilities.BrowserFactory.closeModalPopup(BrowserFactory.java:412)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:48:48       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:48:48       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
11:48:48       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
11:48:48       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
11:48:48       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
11:48:48       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:48:48
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably in your catch{UnhandledAlertException e) block handle it by providing:

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

 alert.accept();
```

Comment: @kushal.if i try to catch the unepected alert exception by adding node code to the catch block, do you know why still gets outputted to the console window?

Comment: Because the Alert is still open and catch{UnhandledAlertException e) is just ignoring it, but not handling it explicitly

Comment: after deeply looking into the code i have found the problem